# Travis-CI and Magento 2 setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, travis

I've tried setting up Travis CI on a new empty Magento 2 Github repo (https://github.com/Tjitse-E/TravisTest).

Part of my Travis configuration file:

```
install:
   - echo "{\"http-basic\":{\"repo.magento.com\":{\"username\":\"${MAGENTO_USERNAME}\",\"password\":\"${MAGENTO_PASSWORD}\"}}}" > auth.json
   - composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist
   - mysql -e 'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS magentotravis'
   - mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS magentotravis;'
   - php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://magebuild.integrations.p1-test.de/build/
     --db-host=localhost --db-name=test --db-user=root --admin-firstname=test
     --admin-lastname=Demo --admin-email=test@test--admin-user=test
     --admin-password=72q980hdfq2378ga9w87dg6 --language=de_DE --currency=EUR --timezone=Europe/Berlin
   - php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   - php bin/magento setup:di:compile
   - php bin/magento cache:clean
   - php bin/magento index:reindex
```

I've intentionally installed a module that triggers an error/warning with the command `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`. I want Travis CI to recognize the error and then stop the build. Would this be possible?

Travis output:

```
41.78s$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 46.0 MiB%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 46.0 MiBProxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 46.0 MiB
Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 52.0 MiB
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 52.0 MiB
Repositories code generation... 2/7 [========>-------------------]  28% 5 secs 154.0 MiB
Service data attributes generation... 2/7 [========>-------------------]  28% 5 secs 154.0 MiB
Service data attributes generation... 3/7 [============>---------------]  42% 5 secs 154.0 MiB
Application code generator... 3/7 [============>---------------]  42% 5 secs 154.0 MiB
Application code generator... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 13 secs 174.0 MiB
Interceptors generation... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 13 secs 174.0 MiB
Interceptors generation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 23 secs 192.0 MiB
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 23 secs 192.0 MiB
Area configuration aggregation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 33 secs 268.0 MiB
Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 33 secs 268.0 MiBErrors during compilation:
    Travis\Block\TestClass\TestClass
        Incorrect dependency in class Travis\Block\TestClass\TestClass in /home/travis/build/Tjitse-E/TravisTest/app/code/Travis/Sample/Block/TestClass.php
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
Total Errors Count: 1
Errors during compilation:
    Travis\Block\TestClass\TestClass
        Incorrect dependency in class Travis\Block\TestClass\TestClass in /home/travis/build/Tjitse-E/TravisTest/app/code/Travis/Sample/Block/TestClass.php
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
Total Errors Count: 1
Errors during compilation:
    Travis\Block\TestClass\TestClass
        Incorrect dependency in class Travis\Block\TestClass\TestClass in /home/travis/build/Tjitse-E/TravisTest/app/code/Travis/Sample/Block/TestClass.php
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
Total Errors Count: 1
Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 40 secs 268.0 MiB
Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.
```

The purpose is to automatically test the DI of upgraded third party modules, because they sometimes contain errors in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get it working with the following line added to `install`:

`- if php bin/magento setup:di:compile | grep "Errors during compilation"; then exit 1; fi`